# Validación Phpspreadsheet para crear Excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpspreadsheet

Estoy trabajando con PHPSPREADSHEET para descargar formularios desde mi sistema, todo funciona bien y no tengo mayores inconvenientes con descargar los archivos, pero tengo una situación que espero alguien me pueda orientar para intentar resolverlo.

Lo que pasa es que si hago una consulta a mi Base de datos MYSQL aplicando ciertos criterios que defino, y luego descargo el Excel con la información, ocurre lo siguiente: si en la base de datos existen registros los muestra en el Excel, por el contrario, si no existe nada el Excel es descargado en blanco.

Y es aquí en donde tengo un error, ya que para validar si existe información en la base de datos, en PHPSPREADSHEET hice una consulta, y si no encuentra información, de igual manera descarga el Excel, pero al intentar abrirlo me muestra un error, obviamente porque no se crea la hoja.
Me gustaría que alguien me pueda ayudar para saber si existe alguna manera de devolver algún mensaje cuando no existe información y por lo tanto, el Excel no puede ser creado y menos descargado. Busque en la documentación de la librería pero no encontré nada.

En mi formulario tengo la opción para descargar el Excel, pasándole algunos parámetros para realizar la consulta en PHPSPREADSHEET.

**FORMULARIO**

```
 <a href="FORM.php?id_1=<?php echo $id_est; ?>&id_2=<?php echo $id_sem; 
 ?>"><img src="img/excel.png" title="Descargar Excel"></a>
```

**PHPSPREADSHEET**

```
$id_est= $_REQUEST['id_1'];
$id_sem= $_REQUEST['id_2'];

 $squery= mysqli_query($conec,"SELECT * FROM prueba 
 WHERE establecimiento = $id_est and semestre = $id_sem");

 $result = mysqli_num_rows($squery);

 if($result > 0)
 {
   $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
   $spreadsheet->getProperties()
   ->setCreator('SOLICITUD')
   ->setTitle('SOLICITUD.')
   ->setDescription('Solicitudes')
   ->setKeywords('Excel')
  ->setCategory('PRUEBA');

   $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('PRUEBA');

   $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial')->setSize(8);
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(FALSE)->setScale(100);
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(100);

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="SOLICITUD.xlsx"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
   $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
   $writer->save('php://output');
 }
```

Comment: Hola SBK22. Se me ocurre podrías realizar los siguientes pasos: 1. Hacer una llamada ajax para saber si la consulta va a devolver información (eg: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM prueba WHERE...`). 2. En base a la respuesta obtenida ofrecer (_o no_) el link de descargar del Excel.

Comment: Aunque ahora que lo veo de nuevo... en realidad, no necesitarías hacer un `ajax` dado que podes hacer la consulta ANTES de ofrecer el link.

Comment: [`mysqli_num_rows` depende del buffer, como se explica en la doc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php): *El comportamiento de mysqli_num_rows() depende de si es que se utilizan resultsets con o sin buffer. En caso de emplearlos sin buffer mysqli_num_rows() **no retornará el número de filas correcto hasta que todas las filas del resultado hayan sido recuperadas**.* Si se especifican consultas sin buffer, te dará `0` si lo llamas antes de leer los datos y puede que en consultas que devuelvan gran cantidad de datos ...

Comment: ... el manejador se ponga en modo sin búfer (esto es una suposición mía). El hecho es que no deberías confiar en funciones como `mysqli_num_rows` para saber si hay datos en consultas del tipo `SELECT`. Más bien, haz una verificación **basada en los mismos datos** o haz un `SELECT COUNT(*)`. Para este caso, tú puedes leer los datos y construir dentro de ese bloque tu archivo y fuera de él emitir el mensaje de que no hubo datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé lo que esté pasando con tus datos, pero lo que es cierto es que el Manual de PHP es bastante claro con respecto a [`mysqli_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) (las negritas son mías):

> El comportamiento de `mysqli_num_rows()` depende de si es que se
> utilizan resultsets con o sin buffer. En caso de emplearlos sin buffer
> `mysqli_num_rows()` **no retornará el número de filas correcto hasta
> que todas las filas del resultado hayan sido recuperadas**.

Si esto es así, entonces hay que concluir que `mysqli_num_rows()` **no es confiable para saber la cantidad de filas que trajo una consulta `SELECT`**. En ese sentido, el Manual es más claro cuando habla del equivalente de esta función en PDO (`rowCount()`), dice que no se debe confiar en ella para contar datos con un `SELECT`, por más que haya millones de ejemplos de código usando una y otra.

Vamos a ver un ejemplo, que puedes probar con cualquier consulta que estés seguro que arroje datos:

```
$sql="SELECT todayDate FROM calendar LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql,MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
printf("Filas encontradas antes de la lectura: %d %s",$result->num_rows,PHP_EOL);
while( $row = $result->fetch_row() ){
    printf("%s %s",$row[0],PHP_EOL);
};
printf("Filas encontradas después de la lectura: %d %s",$result->num_rows,PHP_EOL);
```

La salida de este código es:

```
Filas encontradas antes de la lectura: 0 
20221110 
20221111 
20221112 
Filas encontradas después de la lectura: 3
```

¿Por qué la misma propiedad da primero `0` y luego `3`? Porque era una consulta que dependía del buffer, al pasarle como segundo paràmetro a `query` la constante: `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`.

Biienn, *pero mi consulta no tiene esa constante, por tanto **debe** ser sin buffer y **debe** funcionar*. Nadie te asegura eso, no sabes (y esto es suposición mía), si el manejador puede meter en el buffer una consulta que arroja demasiados datos por ejemplo, para optimizar.

### Una solución de conveniencia

En un contexto como este, la forma más segura de saber si hay datos es organizando el código. Por ejemplo, puede usar una variable para recoger los datos y verificar esa variable.

```
$result = $mysqli->query( ... );

/*
   Dentro del while gestiona tu contenido
   sea metiéndolo directamente
   sea concatenando en una variable
   Esto segundo te permite hacer la verificación
   en base a esa misma variable
   viendo si sigue vacía después del while
*/
$data="";
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    //Aquí concatena $data
    $data.=$row[...];
};
/*
   Aquí verificas $data para 
   mandar el archivo o lo que se requiera
*/
if ($data) {
    //Había filas, hacer lo que proceda
} else {
    //No había filas
}
```

### La mejor de las soluciones

Para saber si hay datos en una tabla, nada mejor que contar esas filas. Ahí, ni buffer ni historias, sabras con toda certeza lo que hay.

Y, no hay que tener miedo del rendimiento. Si tus tablas están bien diseñadas, lo más rápido seguirá siendo ejecutar una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM laTabla WHERE losCriterios;`.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el problema resida en la validación que estás utilizando en el condicional "if". Te sugiero que pruebes algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
if(count($squery) > 0){
  ....tu código
} else {
  echo "No hay datos disponibles para descargar.";
}
```

Si la solución propuesta anteriormente no funciona, te recomiendo utilizar las funciones `print_r()` o `var_dump()` para imprimir y validar la información que se está recibiendo cuando el archivo no debe descargarse. Esto nos permitirá identificar el problema con mayor facilidad y encontrar una solución adecuada.

Comment: Te agradezco por responder, pero la validación no tiene problemas. Lo que busco es una manera de manejar la validación cuando no hay datos en la consulta.