# SELECT sin WHERE no muestra resultado array []

Tags: php, mysql, array, json

Tengo un problema con mi consulta para extraer el listado de todos los proveedores

getUsers.php

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM proveedores ";
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$val = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $val['response'] = "Success";
        $val['data'][] = $res;
    }
} else {
    $val['response'] = "There is no data";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($val);
?>
```

No muestra resultado alguno cuando debería mostrarme un arreglo con todo lo de la tabla.
Ni siquiera un array vacío, solo me deja la página en blanco.

getUsers.php con where

¿Por qué si mi consulta contiene un WHERE sí me muestra un resultado?

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE name = 'APTIV PACKARD C/O FIDELMA EJIOGU'";
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$val = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $val['response'] = "Success";
        $val['data'][] = $res;
    }
} else {
    $val['response'] = "There is no data";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($val);
?>

El resultado 
{
    "response": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "38",
            "supplier": "DEL0",
            "name": "APTIV PACKARD C/O FIDELMA EJIOGU",
            "new_mrp": "Vicente Buendia",
            "planner": "Hector Soto"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás usando `mysqli_num_rows` para determinar si una consulta trajo datos y **no deberías hacerlo** por más que haya tutoriales que enseñen esta **mala práctica**.

Y es que [el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) es claro con respecto a esto:

> El comportamiento de `mysqli_num_rows()` depende de si es que se
> utilizan resultsets con o sin buffer. En caso de emplearlos sin buffer
> `mysqli_num_rows()` no retornará el número de filas correcto hasta que
> todas las filas del resultado hayan sido recuperadas.

Puede que el SGBD, o el servidor, o quien sea, considere que el caso de tu consulta que trae los datos sin filtrar sería demasiado grande, metiendo los resultados en el buffer. Si eso ocurre `mysqli_num_rows()` retornará `0` en tu código porque las filas están en el buffer (revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/605292/29967), donde ocurre algo parecido, hay un ejemplo de funcionamiento de `mysqli_num_rows()`).

### Solución

Tú puedes **verificar los mismos datos en este caso**, para saber si hay filas o no. Simplemente, declaras el array vacío al principio y verificas **si después del `while` dicho array sigue vacío**, lo cual significará que no hubo datos.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código quedaría así. Mejoraremos tres cosas más:

- Una verificación del éxito de la consulta
- Evitar meter caaaada vez `$val['response'] = "Success";` dentro de los datos. Es una bandera que debería ir por fuera. Tenerla dentro del `while` es **redundante**.
- Lo mismo ocurre con la clave `data`, puesta cada vez dentro del `while`. La misma debe ir también por fuera, como clave para todas las filas de datos que hayan sido encontradas (todo el crédito a @gbianchi en este punto, el cual no vi inicialmente).
- Poner tipo de codificación en la cabecera. Pues si en la respuesta hay datos con acentos o caracteres especiales, el JSON podría quedar inválido.

---

```
<?php

    include 'db.php';
    /*
       Usaremos la variable $data,
       declarada inicialmente como un array vacío 
       para recoger los datos de cada fila 
       y al mismo tiempo para determinar si 
       no se encontraron filas, 
       ya que si el código no pasa por el while
       $data seguirá siendo un array vacío.
       Esto sustituirá en la lógica del código 
       el uso de mysqli_num_rows
    */   
    $data = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM proveedores";
    if ( $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ) {
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            $data[] = $res;
        }
        /*
           Aquí verificamos el estado de $data.
           Si tiene datos, pondremos la clave success en response
           Y pondremos una clave date con todas las filas
           De lo contrario, pondremos la clave error.
           Ambas cosas quedan fuera del while, 
           pues eran redundantes allí y alteraban
           la estructura del resultado.
        */
        if($data) {
            $val=array('response'=>'success',
                       'data'=>$data);              
         } else {
            $val=array('response'=>'error',
                       'msg'=>'No se encontraron filas');
        }
    } else {
        /*
           Esto es si la consulta falla.
           Pondremos en response la bandera Error
           Y pondremos además un mensaje
        */
        $val=array('response'=>'error',
                   'msg'=>'Error ejecutando la consulta');        
    }
    
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($val);
?>
```

Donde se consume esta respuesta, verificarías con algo como esto en pseudo código:

```
respuesta 

if (respuesta.response=='success') {
    Hay datos
    Leer en un bucle las filas que estarían en respuesta.data
} else {
    No hay datos
    Imprimir respuesta.msg
}
```

Cabe decir que para simplificar, tú podrías mandar un booleano, por ejemplo asociado a la palabra `status`. En el código PHP sería, para el caso de éxito:

```
$val['status']=true;
```

Y para el caso de error:

```
$val['status']=false;
```

En la fila donde verificas después del `while`, sería simplemente:

```
$val['status'] = (bool)($val) ;
```

Esto meterá en `status` un booleano, `true` si `$val` tiene datos, o `false` si no tiene datos.

La verificación sería más natural, basada en un booleano:

```
if (respuesta.status) {
    Hay datos
} else {
    No hay datos
    Imprimir respuesta.msg
}
```

#### Demo

Con estos cambios debería funcionar, salvo otros errores que hayas cometido adaptando el código, o propios de tu contexto.

Aquí te dejo una <kbd>[**DEMOSTRACIÓN**](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/85feb41243073215c4a9e7530dc1f085/php/php81/55d7cb1cdaada920d9e32e0bdd14a142/)</kbd>, en una tabla con tres filas, vas a obtener esto:

```
{
  "response":"success",
  "data":[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "proveedor":"Papirus S. A."
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "proveedor":"Parker"
    },
    {
      "id":"3",
      "proveedor":"Montblanc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Si observas, la respuesta tiene **dos claves** una llamada `response` con valor `success` y otra llamada `data` con los datos de las tres filas que tiene la tabla de prueba. Para mostrar cada fila, debes iterar `data` como es lógico.

Comment: Buen dia gracias por la respuesta, sabes que utilice la primera seccion donde viene la consulta y si me funciono bien pero cuando utilizo el mismo codigo en el servidor que tengo me muestra solo la pantalla en blanco.

No se si tiene mucho que ver que en mi laptop que ejecuto las pruebas contiene php 8 y en el servidor tienen php 5.6.9 por que en dicho servidor es donde si funciona solamanete la consulta con el where pero sin el es donde me muestra la pantalla en blanco

Comment: @AlbertoCruz lo único que podría ser incompatible con PHP 5.6 sería esto: `$val['response'] = ($val) ? "success" : "error";` No recuerdo en qué versión se incluyó el operador ternario. En ese caso, lo puedes cambiar por un `if`, algo así: **`if($val) { $val['response'] = "success"; } else { $val['response'] = "error"; }`** Sería bueno que veas el log de errores para ver por qué estaría fallando exactamente.

Comment: Sabes que ejecuto directamente el archivo en el navegador y la seccion de consola no me muestra ningun error, incluso uso postman y tampoco me muestra algun error como tal solo no me muestra el array.

Por eso es que me parece extraño que solo con el where me muestre el resultado 
Pero igual deja utilizo eso que me acabas de sugerir.

Comment: Ya reemplace la linea de codigo por el if y aun asi continua sin mostrar el resultado solo con el where aun y no encuentro la verdad a que se debe este problema por que la tabla si existe los registros.

Comment: @AlbertoCruz agrega estas tres líneas al inicio del script PHP: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Luego graba y prueba de nuevo. Así podrás ver en pantalla cuál es el error. OJO: esto es para una depuración rápida. No deberías hacer esto en todos tus archivos, sino [revisar el log de errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967).

Comment: pregunta tecnica: en cualquier lenguaje normal, esto no tendria sentido: while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            $val['data'][] = $res;
        } porque estarias asociando al mismo lugar de data cada resultado.. en php eso es distinto?? lo manda a otra fila del array o que hace???

Comment: Cierto @gbianchi ese es otro error. Cuando pueda actualizo.

Comment: Elimine lo que ocmentaba @gbianchi y deje mi linea solamente asi  `$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results); $val['data'][] = $res;` y me devolvio ahora si una respuesta pero en ves de mostrarme todos los resultados solo me devuelve uno `{"data":[{"id":"1","supplier":"500","name":"COMPONENT PLANT","new_mrp":"Lupita Zamora","planner":"Jesus Rodriguez"}],"response":"success"}` lo cual significa que el problema se encuentra en el while `while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { $val['data'][] = $res; }`

Comment: @AlbertoCruz fijate que Cedano no cambio asi el codigo, lo hizo de otra forma.. el es el experto en esto, fijate como dejo el codigo...

Comment: @AlbertoCruz actualicé el código, poniendo todas las filas dentro de un array llamado `$data` y luego fuera del `while` poniendo en `$val` una clave `data` con todas las filas. Inicialmente no me percaté de ese otro fallo que estaba en tu código original. Debes revisar el nuevo código de la respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo implemente y me muestra la pantalla en blanco sin resultados, pero como te comento si elimino el while si me devuelve un solo resultado

Comment: @AlbertoCruz ¿podrías editar la pregunta, poniendo debajo tu nueva versión del código, así como la forma en que estás manejando la respuesta del mismo? Así se podrá revisar qué es lo que estás haciendo mal.

Comment: @AlbertoCruz he actualizado la respuesta, aclarando mejor los nuevos cambios. Y al final he agregado una demostración. El código debe funcionar, a no ser que haya otros errores propios de tu contexto o en la adaptación del código.

Comment: creo que es problema del servidor como te comente esta utilizando php 5.6.9 y mysql 5.7 command line y en mi computadora cuento con XAMPP y en mi equipo si me ejecuta correctamente tu respuesta pero lo ejecuto en el serivdor y solo me muestra una pantalla en blanco pero en realidad no se a que se deba por que te digo que si elimino el while lo corre perfecto pero mostrando un solo resultado y con el where igual devuelve respuesta.

Comment: Incluso en el archivo db.php agregue validacion de conexion y al ejecutar tu respuesta me devuelve `Connected successfully` pero solo eso no me devuelve el array

Comment: @AlbertoCruz revisa el log de errores del equipo donde no funciona. Es un problema de la infraestructura, no del código. Tampoco es problema de versión, todo el código es compatible con PHP 5.6

Comment: Sabes que estoy ejecutando el php desde postman pongo la ip del servidor con la ruta del archivo y aun asi no me muestra algun log de error ni en postman ni en la consola del navegador

Comment: el archivo lo estoy utilizando para una aplicacion kotlin todos los demas php me funcionan correctamente a excepcion de este

Comment: Le agregue un `var_dump($data);` despues del `$data[] = $res;` y ahora si me devuelve los datos del array

Comment: @AlbertoCruz debes revisar el log de errores del servidor, donde estás ejecutando el archivo `.php`, no en postman ni en Javascript.

Comment: Entre a ala carpeta logs de php en el servidor y no tengo ningun archivo generado es lo mas raro

Comment: Ya revise el log de apache y no me muestra errores de un rango de 1 hora que es en el rango que he estado haciendo pruebas

Comment: Por fin pude hacer que funcionara, el problema era en la tabla al parecer se creo incorrectamente por eso no mostraba los registros la volvi a crear y ingrese nuevamente los registros y ya me devuelve el arreglo correctamente